# Component scan in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am learning about Spring MVC and I have created one root web application context using the context listener. From what I have read this is used to declare beans such as service beans etc and the dispatcher servlets inherits from the root context.

I have added the component scan XML element in the root context. It scans all the packages including those with `@Controller`. So why doesn't the URL for the controller until I add another component scan in the dispatcher context? Would it be duplicate bean definitions? And is this even correct?

Should I add component scan in the root context only for the services packages etc. and then the component scan element in the dispatcher context only for the controller package?

*Removed namspaces from context files.*

From dispatcher context:

```
<beans>
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.controller"/>-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>    
</beans>
```

Root context:

```
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>defaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/webContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>defaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: could you paste here your context xml?

Comment: and please provide web.xml too

Comment: @JavaMentor Added now

Comment: duplicates [applicationContext not finding Controllers for Servlet context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453530/applicationcontext-not-finding-controllers-for-servlet-context) There is well explained the problem, basically its because at the filter level you don't have a web context, within the servlet level you have the annotation drive mvc that will create a needed `RequestMappingInfo`