# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, openid

I have been struggling at successfully implementing openId in spring from last 3 weeks now.
Please help me out with it.

I tried to implement it from http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html, now i m getting an exception.
console log:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openid4java/consumer/ConsumerException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:884)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 28 more
```

my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  

 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-       class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping> 

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

Dispatcher.servlet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kratin" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <!-- Default converters -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean> 

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.kratin.domain.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

spring-security.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/rest/auth/denied" >

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <!-- Adding the openid-login tag activates Spring Security's support for OpenID  -->
    <security:openid-login
            login-page="/rest/auth/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/rest/auth/login?error=true" 
            default-target-url="/rest/main/common"/>

    <security:logout 
            invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/rest/auth/login" 
            logout-url="/rest/auth/logout"/>

</security:http>

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
                <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

 <!-- An in-memory list of users. No need to access an external database layer.
        See Spring Security 3.1 Reference 5.2.1 In-Memory Authentication -->
 <security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <!-- user name is based on the returned OpenID identifier from Google -->
    <security:user name="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItxxioJSDLFJLjxcksdfjOpAASDFosSSoJ0E" 
                        password="" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
 </security:user-service>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
 For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kratin" />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Have you read the stacktrace? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openid4java/consumer/ConsumerException` looks quite clear to me. You are missing referenced libraries... Probably a openid4java jar (or maybe you have a too old version).

Comment: Another thing to notice is you are duplicating all your bean instances. Both the `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` do a `<context:component-scan base-package="com.kratin" />` This will eventually lead you to other problems.

Comment: Thank you for the opinion i was using an older version of jar. Can u please specify how can i remove these duplications so that it wont hamper the execution. I m new to spring and hibernate so might be really stupid to ask but i need to know. Also if you have any suggestions or ideas regarding openId implementation in spring and extracting emailId and name it would be helpful.

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453530/applicationcontext-not-finding-controllers-for-servlet-context

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace shows that you are referencing a missing library:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException

Either you do not have <kbd>openid4java</kbd> installed or you have an older version of <kbd>openid4java</kbd> that doesn't contain the needed class.

You should install the correct version of <kbd>openid4java</kbd>