# Null pointer exception when using @Autowired annotation to inject bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, autowired

---

When I use @Autowired annotation to inject dao to service,java.lang.NullPointerException occurred.I can't fix it.Please anyone help!

**exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sargeras.login.service.LoginServiceImpl.register(LoginServiceImpl.java:14)
```

**service**

```
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{
@Autowired
private LoginDao loginDao;
public int register(UserVo userVo){
    return loginDao.register(userVo);
}
}
```

**dao**

```
@Repository
public class LoginDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements LoginDao {
@Override
public int register(UserVo userVo) {
    int result = -1;
    return result;
}
```

**springmvc.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sargeras" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean name="loginService" class="com.sargeras.login.service.LoginServiceImpl">
</bean>
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
    <property name="username" value="sargeras" />
    <property name="password" value="sargeras" />
</bean>
<bean name="loginDao" class="com.sargeras.login.repository.LoginDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController extends BaseController{
@Autowired
private LoginService service;
@RequestMapping(value = "validate")
public void toLogin(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    logger.error("hhhh");
    response.getWriter().print(" this is to logging 1");
}
@RequestMapping(value="register")
public void register(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws   Exception{
    UserVo user = new UserVo();
    int result = 0;
    String userName = (String)request.getParameter("usernamesignup");
    String userPassword = (String)request.getParameter("passwordsignup_confirm");
    String userEmail = (String)request.getParameter("emailsignup");
    user.setUserName(userName);
    user.setUserPassword(userPassword);
    user.setUserEmail(userEmail);
    result = service.register(user);
    if(result == 1){
        response.getWriter().print("Success");
    }
}
}
```

service is used in controller and can be injected successfully

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>spring_test</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/config/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/config/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

** this is my web.xml configuration**

****problem resolved as follows ****

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/config/spring-servlet.xml,
        classpath:/config/applicationContext*.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Application context and servlet context can not be mixed,I'll keep that in mind.Thank you all!

Comment: Show us where you are using the `loginService` bean.

Comment: can spring now Autowire private fields or are setters not showed in sample?

Comment: @LorenzoBoccaccia yes, private field injections are supported

Comment: what's weird is that it can be successfully injected in controller,but can't make it work in service.what have I missed?

Comment: can you post your servlet configuration?

Comment: Why your context as they are, you will get a bunch of duplicate beans, some in root context, some in servlet context. Read up on the difference between the two.

Comment: You should add <context:annotation-config/> to enable autowiring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't posted your servlet configuration, but I suspect that you are mixing application context and servlet context. They are two independent bean containers. It is discussed here:
[applicationContext not finding Controllers for Servlet context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453530/applicationcontext-not-finding-controllers-for-servlet-context#11471568)

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested you are indeed mixing up the servletContext and the applicationContext. Either have your servletContext(applicationContext.xml file) import the springmvc.xml file or put the mvc-annotation-driven tag in the applicationContext.xml file. Either way you should read up on how to structure your contexts properly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, ditch the springmvc.xml and add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sargeras" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your applicationContext.xml.

taht should be sufficient